# How do you play a video in your app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a video saved in my xcode project that I want to play as a response to a button click. Does IOS have built in media API's to handle that? Could anyone give the class name that handles video on the iPhone?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/_index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code to get you started:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourfilename" ofType:@"m4v"]]];
        [[moviePlayerController view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, parentView.frame.size.width, parentView.frame.size.height)];
        [moviePlayerController setShouldAutoplay:NO];
        [moviePlayerController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];
        [[moviePlayerController backgroundView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
```

By the documentation you have to set the MPMoviePlayerController's frame with a frame as big as the parent view's.

Comment: Thank you, I will do something very similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

MPMoviePlayerViewController.  Please search a little bit before asking questions.

Comment: Sorry, I had seen that somewhere but it didn't work right off.

Answer (score 0):

Yes iOS does contain media API's to handle that.